# DefaultGroovyMethod sort leads to version change and database update

Tags: sorting, grails, groovy, grails-orm, sql-update

I have a List of domain objects which I want to sort by a specific property. Groovy provides a lot of functions to handle lists in a "simple"/"groovy" way.

The problem is that something like

```
myDomainList.sort{it.position}
```

leads to an update of `version` in `myDomain-Table`. 
What I want is the expected sort behavior without (any) hibernate-call (database change).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` mutates the collection it is working on unless you use it like this:

```
myDomainList.sort( false ) { it.position }
```

This [variation of sort](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#sort(java.lang.Iterable,%20boolean,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) which takes 3 parameters, first being the Iterable itself, second `boolean` (to decide whether to mutate or create a new collection instead of mutating the original collection) and 3rd parameter being the closure.

In the former case, when `sort` modifies the list then domain class is marked as dirty, hence a flush becomes imminent on transaction close.

Comment: You can also use `myDomainList.toSorted { it.position }`.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Correct, but that is only available from Groovy 2.4. If OP is using an older version of Grails which does not support Groovy 2.4, `toSorted()` will not be applicable.